# Cisco router password change and now select VOIP phones not working

Tags: cisco, router, voip

I manage this school network and I went in today to reset the password on their Cisco 2800 series router.  I didn't have the original password on the system because it wasn't shared with me and the only person that knew it had left, so I had to do the password recovery steps from [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps259/products_password_recovery09186a0080094675.shtml).

The password recovery went fine and I was able to change the passwords on the router to something new.  I did change the password for the "web admin" under "telephony-service" section also in my password resetting routines.

So after I did all this all was seeming to work fine, until I was about to leave and found out that some office phones weren't working, and some were.  The model phones that weren't working were the Cisco 7960 IP Phones, but the models that were working were the Cisco 7906 IP Phones.  The 7960 phones were taking a long time to sync up with the VOIP server, which is the router.  After a while the phone would say "Configuring VLAN", then it would goto "Configuring IP", then after a short time on that it would say "no load specified" and repeat the same process over and over.  I've done some research and the "no load specified" refers to the phone not being able to load a configuration from the TFTP server, if I understand correctly.

So..

--Can my password reset operations cause something to happen with the TFTP server authentication?
--How can I check to see if the TFTP server is working fine?
--Why do some phones work fine?

[This is the running-config](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:8d9).  I didn't change any other settings in the running-config, only reset the passwords, and the phones were working just fine before the password reset.

Also, I'm not a Cisco professional, I know enough to go into the console, and run commands.  So please be thorough with your instructions of things to try and what they mean.  I want to have an understanding of commands before applying them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the phone shows up if you do 'show cdp neighbor' on the switch they connected to?

Comment: They are connected to a LinkSys POE switch, when I run that command on the router it just shows me the FastEthernet interface on the router and "Fas 0/1            129          S I      WS-C3560- Fas 0/1" as the information.

Comment: If you could post the config for the Cisco and the LinkSys if it has one, that would probably get us closer to the problem.

Comment: FYI, I posted a link in my question.

Comment: On the phones having problems, does the Network Configuration on the phones having the correct DHCP Server address?  Do the settings match the other phones?  If not, what are the differences?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the running config?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph, yes, the settings on the phone don't seem to have changed, the information entered into the config seem to match up with information in the running config.

Comment: @Joseph, also, I don't know how to get to the configuration information on the phones that are working, they are the 7906 and have different buttons than the 7960 phones.

Comment: Press the button with the globe on it to the right of the up and down arrow button and choose Settings > Network Configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the router was hacked or sabotaged remotely by the old company or people that managed the network.  There was some political things happening at the time.  It required calling Cisco for support in getting the phones operational again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Joseph, above. Let's start from the bottom of the network and work up.

1. Are the 7960's getting a good IP address?  Press the Settings key, choose Network Configuration, and (I think) IPv4 Configuration (or IP address). Is the IP address sane?
2. Are the 7960's receiving the option 150 properly from the DHCP server? Using the above method, does the TFTP server show 172.16.10.1?
3. Are the 7960's asking for something weird from the TFTP server? Get into the 2800 and issue "debug ip tftp". From a console you'll see error messages. From a Telnet or SSH session, issue "terminal monitor" and you'll get the error messages. On a phone reboot, what do they ask for?
4. What about the 7940's (ephone 2-4)? Do they work?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what happened is that the phones were added to the running config on the router.  The running config was never copied to nvram.  When you reset the password, the nvram config is what was used to boot up the router.

Since some phones work, I bet that everything is working just fine.  You probably just need to reconfig the phones into the system.

Comment: The phones are still in the running config, for example, extension 101 is in the system:

!
ephone-dn  2  dual-line
 number 101
 label Extension 101
 description Extension 101
 name Extension 101
 call-forward busy 900
 call-forward noan 900 timeout 10
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
!
ephone  2
 mac-address 001C.58F9.2A0D
 username "user" password pass
 type 7940
 button  1:2
!

Also, what you speak of, if the running config was not copied to nvram, wouldn't rebooting the router lose the phones?  If so, I have rebooted this router before without losing phone functionality.

Comment: Well, that didn't work out too well.  Sorry for the lack of formatting for easy reading.

Comment: If you rebooted before and didn't loose the phones, then I missed it with my guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a CISCO router password change, learn how it is done easily in a few steps, here:

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/92933.aspx

Comment: This isn't helpful at all.